# change last character from parameter if it is '+' or '-'

Tags: xstring

i want to use the package `xstring` to create a new command to change the last character

for example if  i have 2+ i want to display 2 plus, if 2- then 2 minus , but if i have 2-3 then i want to change nothing

those two commands `\StrSubstitute` and  `\IfEndWith`  from the `xstring` package should do the job , but im really dont know how to write a command to apply it on all the document . thanks for help

Comment: Looking like you want to provide some kind of verbal expression of grades. Why should 2- become `2 minus`, but `2+` remain `2 +` or is that a typo and meant `2 plus`? In fact, ultimately you're trying to apply some replacement in the whole document which is not `xstring` is meant for. Perhaps any program doing regex replacement is better

Comment: upss i meant 2 plus @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer im really noob with latex , have an idea where can i find some help how to write a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suitable regex replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (\+|\-) \Z } { \c{gmasa_pm:N} \1 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\cs_new:Nn \gmasa_pm:N
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {+}{\nobreakspace plus}
    {-}{\nobreakspace minus}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{2-}

\foo{2+}

\foo{2-3}

\end{document}
```

Choose a better name than `\foo`.

The search is for either `+` or `-` that are at the end of the string, because `\Z` matches the end of the input string (you can also use the more common `$` token, for this). Such a `+` or `-` is replaced by itself preceded by `\gmasa_pm:N`, which is defined to look at the next token and produce `~plus` or `~minus` accordingly.

[image]

Without regular expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
  % print all the items except the last one
  \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 }
  % check the last item; if it is + or -, act accordingly, or just print it
  \str_case_e:nnF { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {
    {+}{\nobreakspace plus}
    {-}{\nobreakspace minus}
   }
   { \tl_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{2-}

\foo{2+}

\foo{2-3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @egreg , im receiving this (|)g2-2-  when im using \foo{2-}, im really dont understanding the regex expressions ,is there a way to use the xstring package ?

Comment: same for \foo{Note 2+} im receiving (|)g‘2+2+

Comment: @GmaSa No error message?

Comment: unfortunately no , thats when im using your first example with regular expression , without regular expression im receiving 2-12-1 minus for \foo{2-}

Comment: @GmaSa What context are using the macro in?

Comment: i have a variable that may be change over time , i should everytime check if it ends with + or - and replace the text with the xstring  for example \StrSubstitute{\myVar}{+}{ plus}{} that works fine i should now integrate \IfEndWith and check if it ends with a - using this command \IfEndWith

Comment: @GmaSa Sorry, but I don't follow. Please, make a new question with the context, adding as much information as necessary. Mixing `xparse` and `expl3` commands with `xstring` ones is a sure recipe for disaster.

Comment: `\str_case_x:nnF` is depreciated, use `\str_case_e:nnTF` instead. Also, `\tl_count:n { #1 } - 1` can be replaced with `-2`.

Comment: @TakingItCasual Yes, but that was before some changes to the functions. I'll edit. Thanks.